# Output folder name to a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
source_files = sorted(Path('path/folder/subfolder1').glob('**/*.csv'))

dataframes = []
for file in source_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['date', 'cost', 'percent'])
    df['Instance Number'] = file.name[:-4]
    df['Source'] = folder.name
    dataframes.append(df)

all = pd.concat(dataframes)

all.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

I'm getting an error for df['Source'] = folder.name because folder isn't defined. How do I add the name of the folder the files come from to a column? I added the name of the file successfully, now I just need to add the name of the folder.

Comment: your `folder.name` should be part of the `source_files`, you could split it using `/` delimiter and get the folder name. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm looking to add the folder name to the output in a column

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `file.parent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using the pathlib library. You can get the folder name where the file is stored by using the `parent` method:

```
df['Source'] = file.parent
```

This should work!

Comment: Hi, this worked. Is there a way to just get the folder name? it gives out C:/Users/Me/FolderName when I only want 'FolderName'

Comment: So, in that case you should use the `parts` method that returns a tuple giving access to the path's various components. I would do it like this: `file.parts[-2]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file))
```

`os.path.dirname(file)` returns the directory name of the file. `os.path.basename` returns a string value which represents the base name of the specified path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please add some more details of why/how this should work?

Comment: 'os.path.dirname(file)' returns the directory name of the file. 'os.path.basename' returns a string value which represents the base name of the specified path.